# SQLCipher cocoapods multiple redefinition errors

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, sqlcipher

While integrating SQLCipher with cocoapods I’m getting multiple redefinition errors.

Version: 4.5.2

```
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:723:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_file'
struct sqlite3_file {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:735:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_file {
       ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:822:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_io_methods'
struct sqlite3_io_methods {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:834:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_io_methods {
       ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:1427:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_vfs'
struct sqlite3_vfs {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:1439:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_vfs {
       ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:1724:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_mem_methods'
struct sqlite3_mem_methods {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:1736:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_mem_methods {
       ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:6999:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_module'
struct sqlite3_module {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:6885:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_module {
       ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:7139:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_index_info'
struct sqlite3_index_info {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:7025:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_index_info {
       ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:7142:10: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_index_constraint'
  struct sqlite3_index_constraint {
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:7028:10: note: previous definition is here
  struct sqlite3_index_constraint {
         ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:7149:10: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_index_orderby'
  struct sqlite3_index_orderby {
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:7035:10: note: previous definition is here
  struct sqlite3_index_orderby {
         ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:7154:10: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_index_constraint_usage'
  struct sqlite3_index_constraint_usage {
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:7040:10: note: previous definition is here
  struct sqlite3_index_constraint_usage {
         ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:7285:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_vtab'
struct sqlite3_vtab {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:7171:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_vtab {
       ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:7309:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_vtab_cursor'
struct sqlite3_vtab_cursor {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:7195:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_vtab_cursor {
       ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:7814:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_mutex_methods'
struct sqlite3_mutex_methods {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:7699:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_mutex_methods {
       ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:8570:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_pcache_page'
struct sqlite3_pcache_page {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:8445:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_pcache_page {
       ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:8735:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_pcache_methods2'
struct sqlite3_pcache_methods2 {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:8610:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_pcache_methods2 {
       ^
<module-includes>:2:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:2:
#import "sqlite3ext.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:
#include <sqlite3.h>
         ^
/Users/mukeshyadav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MindTickle-buzymtagwbmstehjmknrjcjxuysn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLCipher/SQLCipher.framework/Headers/sqlite3.h:8758:8: error: redefinition of 'sqlite3_pcache_methods'
struct sqlite3_pcache_methods {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:8633:8: note: previous definition is here
struct sqlite3_pcache_methods {
       ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'SQLite3'
```

I've just added `SQLCipher` pod in pod file

```
  pod 'SQLCipher'
```

Other pods I am using are `AWSS3`, `FirebaseAnalytics`, `Mixpanel` etc.

Comment: I have same issue "Mixpanel" use Sqlite3 that conflict with SQLCipher. Find any soluation?

Comment: Ya same. I removed Mixpanel and it started working fine. Have contacted mix panel support lets see if I get anything.

Comment: I copy "sqlite3.h" and "sqlite3.c" file from SQLCipher pod folder and remove all redefine error. then after replace both file in pod dir it working fine. it is temporary solution.
Ref:- https://github.com/BhaumikSurani/iOS-Note/tree/master/SQLCipher_Redefinition_Error